# Email Masking in widget

Tags: plugins, theme-development

I have a wordpress website in which we have used widgets and we have added html mail  like this

```
<a href="mailto: myemail.examlple.com"> my email </a>
```

I want to protect this email id from spams when user did view source.

I already disabled copy paste.
Any idea?

Comment: Not really a WP question. Try the obfuscator, which will use javascript to hide the address: http://www.jottings.com/obfuscator/

Comment: There's also this http://scr.im/ online..

Answer (score 3):

Try [`antispambot()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/antispambot):

```
<a href="mailto:<?= antispambot('myemail.examlple.com') ?>">
    <?= antispambot('my email') ?>
</a>
```